# Get Instance Url with valid OAuth Access Token

Tags: rest-api

How do I get the Instance URL with just a valid OAuth Access Token?

I don't have any other information, for example, I don't have the client_id or client_secret.

If I make an assumption that the Instance URL is https://na16.salesforce.com, I'm able to use the REST API with the valid OAuth Access Token.

Comment: I'd love to find this out as well.

Comment: Have you solved this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

You need valid client_id and client_secret in order to request a valid token to perform API requests.
You can obtain these alphanumeric strings by creating a custom app in your org (this may help: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AfcgIAC )

When you've got your client_id and client_secret, follow the instructions I wrote on a different question, it should work for you then:
[Sending data from PHP to Salesforce using CURL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38841/sending-data-from-php-to-salesforce-using-curl/187821#187821)

Comment: The OP literally says he doesn't have a client ID or secret.